# Program to balance speaker output for surround sound 2.1?

Tags: sound

I don't know how to tune speakers well, so I wanted to know if there is a program that will create a balanced sound output when connected to my 2.1 system for all sounds. Using Macbook Pro 2010 15 inch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install [Pulse Audio Volume Controller (aka pavucontrol)](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/).

Open up your Terminal and execute these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol # Install
pavucontrol # Run
```

[image: screenshot of pavucontrol gui]

Comment: NOTE 2024 update... ffor my 5.1 I had to click the lock channels together (to unlock them) button there to get the extra speaker settings, after selecting that Output Tab.  otherwise it was just a left or right. pulseaudio 15.99.1
  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS  you would think it would be this way by default to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it by ear, I would simply download a wide-band pink noise (which is random noise, equal energy per octave - which is the balanced sound you are after) sound file and play it back and set the levels between your speakers until they sound even.

The following link has a series of different test tones and instructions on how to use them: http://www.eminent-tech.com/music/multimediatest.html

Comment: Is there a way I can set sound balance without moving the speakers?

Comment: In the settings control panel > sound you can set left/right balance and subwoofer if connected.

Answer (score 0):

This is about generic stereo L/R channel tuning. Would have [posted it here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839646/how-to-change-left-right-audio-balance) but that question is closed.

---

`pavucontrol` on for example 18.04 does not have balance. Pretty amazing but that is another topic. One can use `pulseeffects` - but this is IMO a both heavy and extreme option to simply tune L/R. It also has the disadvantage of making the complexity of sinks and devices more heavy.

## Other options

### 1. Alsamixer <sup>(commandline)</sup>

`alsamixer` for the core ALSA base.

1. Optionally select card etc.
2. Select control, for example `Headphones`
3. Balance volume: <kbd>B</kbd>
4. Adjust Left: *Decrease:* <kbd>Z</kbd>, *Increase:* <kbd>Q</kbd>
5. Adjust Right: *Decrease:* <kbd>C</kbd>, *Increase:* <kbd>E</kbd>

Simply press <kbd>F1</kbd> for options.

### 2. [Ponymix](https://github.com/falconindy/ponymix) <sup>(commandline)</sup>

For Pulse Audio.

A very simple and light-weight command line tool. It does not come as a package from what I can find and not much happening on the project, but works fine at least on my tests.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/falconindy/ponymix
cd ponymix
make
sudo make install
```

One can also run it locally without install.

```sh
# Get balance
./ponymix get-balance
# Set balance L/R
./ponymix set-balance -- 0
# 50% right
./ponymix set-balance -- 50
# 50% left
./ponymix set-balance -- -50
# Adjust +20% R
./ponymix adjust-balance -- 20
```

The `--` (end of options) is needed for negative values.

It also have commands for volume and mute (set, get), move input / output between devices and generic information listings.