# How to Change Left-Right Audio Balance

Tags: sound, xubuntu, alsa

My headset gives louder sound on the right side. And I change the balance in Windows to hear equal. But I couldn't find where I can balance my audio.

I searched for it but couldn't find.

This is the volume control: [Volume Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3DC.png)
My OS is Xubuntu

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the one linked IMO. This question is about balance in general, the other is about balance on a surround setup. Added another answer there anyway.

Answer (score 17):

Install Pulse Audio Volume Control from the software center and run it:

You will get a screen like this:

[image: pa1]

If your balance sliders are locked together, click the lock in the upper right corner of the window and adjust the left and right balance volumes until you reach the point of satisfaction. For me that's about here:

[image: pa2]

If you then lock the lock again your adjustments will be locked in place and survive a reboot.

Comment: It doesn't work. Second parameter has no effect. I couldn't put the output here but link is this: [output of amixer](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23402610/)

Comment: Your left and right channels appear to be locked in a linked status. Editing answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no for left and right in Pulse Audio. I am using Xubuntu 15.10 and this is my Pulse Audio: [link](http://imgur.com/giPGCUI.png)

Comment: @maydin Actually you are using a version that is no longer supported. See:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: It is the same as @maydin 's on 18.04. No balance option.

Comment: @user3342816 That's unfortunate but unsurprising , as clearly this answer was written in 2016. As this question is closed, perhaps https://askubuntu.com/questions/447870/program-to-balance-speaker-output-for-surround-sound-2-1 will be of more use to you.

Comment: Nah, I find it surprising that such a basic feature is not included form the get-go. Heck, it has been in ALSA since the 90s lol. I posted an answer on the question you linked back in June.