# Maintaining custom left/right audio balance (i.e. ratio) when changing volume level

Tags: pulseaudio

My headphones have aged and one of them (the left one) now plays sounds at a much lower volume than the other. So I adjusted the left-right balance, [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839646/how-to-change-left-right-audio-balance), to (in my case) 80% on the left and 20% on the right. However, locking this balance does not do what I would expect it to do when changing the volume afterwards: Namely, increasing the volume by, say, 5% either through the `pavucontrol` GUI or through e.g. `pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%` will add 5 percentage points to both sides, left and right, i.e. the left & right levels will be at 85% and 25% afterwards. Put differently, the ratio of `80%/20% = 4` is not being preserved and the audio will again sound disbalanced.

How can I change that and maintain the ratio of `4` at all times? Is there a corresponding setting somewhere deep down in PulseAudio or, maybe even better, is there a programmatic way (shell script) to achieve this? (I haven't been able to figure out how to retrieve – let alone adjust – the left/right volume levels individually.)

[EDIT]: As for *setting* different volume levels for the left and right channels, I just noticed that `pactl` allows passing multiple (space-separated) volume levels, one for each channel. Now, I just need to know how to retrieve the current volume level of each channel. As far as I can tell, `pamixer --get-volume` does not allow this (pamixer is [this tool](https://github.com/cdemoulins/pamixer)).

[EDIT 2]: Turns out `pacmd list-sinks` does list the volumes for all channels but, as seems typical for PulseAudio, in a way that's not exactly easy to parse. Is there no easier (future-proof) solution based on a reliable CLI?

Comment: Does `pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5dB` does what you need?

Comment: It does! Or at least it seems to preserve the volume ratio *roughly* (with deviations of `+/-2` percentage points). Seems (sounds) good enough, though. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you like, post this an answer and I will mark it as correct! Your solution definitely gets the job done without having to unnecessarily parse the output of `pacmd` to obtain the volume levels and preserve their ratio.

Comment: Interesting question! Since this is what one usually thinks about increasing volume, this can be always used. Incredibly, this is even more natural than using `pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%` form. For example, one ear I have only 70% of its hearing capacity, this can also be used. Quite funny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase or decrease the volume by `dB` which is a ratio, for example:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5dB
```

As far as I can see with

```
$ pactl list sinks | grep balance
        balance -0.50
```

the balance will remain constant while changing the volume by `dB`.

Here the relevant part of `man pactl`:

> ```
>   set-sink-volume SINK VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
>           Set  the volume of the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical
>           index). VOLUME can be specified as an integer (e.g. 2000, 16384), a  linear  factor
>           (e.g.  0.4,  1.100),  a  percentage  (e.g. 10%, 100%) or a decibel value (e.g. 0dB,
>           20dB).
> ```