# how to change left and right volume levels using pactl

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

The output of anything I record from my system sound using `portaudio` or `parec` is very low in volume.

With a maximum volume as `-49dB` when seen using `ffmpeg -i video.avi -af "volumedetect" -vn -sn -dn -f null /dev/null` from [this](https://superuser.com/a/323127/1049709) answer.

I've spotted the issue to be this

This is the output of

```
pactl list sources
```

```
Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 9995 /  15% / -49.00 dB,   front-right: 9995 /  15% / -49.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd52b0000 irq 132"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

...
```

As you can see `front-left: 9995 /  15% / -49.00 dB,   front-right: 9995 /  15% / -49.00 dB` I need them both to be `100%` I've tried `pactl set-sink-vloume 0 100%` but it does nothing.

I've also tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1206159/971923.

What is the commands to change the left and right both to a `100%`?

I don't see those on `alsamixer` as well.

Using Ubuntu 20.04

I believe the os has nothing to do with the question (I'm asking for a command specific to pactl or related software like alsamixer).

Comment: This works for me : amixer -D pulse sset Master 100% . You can also use increments and decrements like " 10%+ " or " 20%- "

Comment: Please try `pactl set-source-volume 0 100%`. You show `pactl list sources` but you you set the volume of a sink with `pactl set-sink-volume`.

Comment: @mook765 Thank you, that was it could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the volume of the mentioned source with `pactl` you should use the command

```
pactl set-source-volume 0 100%
```

You used

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%
```

which sets the volume of the sink #0 to 100%, that's not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

To change each individual channel, and after having looked everywhere, I finally found it!!

amixer -D pulse sset **Master 100%** = a**ll speakers** to 100%

amixer -D pulse sset **Master Front**  100% = **front** 100% (or whatever you specify)

amixer -D pulse sset Master **Front 100%,50%** = **front left 100% , front right 50 %**

So the same goes for **Master Center, Master Rear, Master Side, Master Woofer**

This took a very long time but finally I got it